# Java Control Panel and command line show different Java 1.7 versions on Mac OS X 10.9.5. What's up?

Tags: java, macos

Running `java_home` shows:

```
> /usr/libexec/java_home -verbose
Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
    1.7.0_45, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
```

But the Java Control Panel says:

[image: Java version reported by Java Control Panel]

What gives? Can anybody explain?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Basically, Mac OS X starts out without any Java, and if any installed application or web site requires Java, it allows you to install a Java JRE.

The JRE is installed with a plain, non-programmer user in mind. It is a runtime environment, has no associated development tools, and includes the Java Webstart. It also comes with a control panel that allows a user to control things such as security, updates etc.

When you want to program with Java on MacOS X, you install a JDK. The JDK is installed in a different path, and generally has no connection to the user-level JRE. That is, it is not reflected in the control panel, which is intended to control the user-level JRE.

Tools intended to work with the JDK will point to the JDK's JRE, and those that are intended to work with the user-level JRE will point to that.

I can't say exactly why they decided to have a full separation between the user Java and the developer Java. But I can offer a guess: Macs can be used by more than one user. Suppose one of those users is a developer and is making changes to the Java installation such as revoking and adding security keys in the keystore, changing the security policy files etc. I suppose Oracle doesn't want those changes in the development Java to affect all the other users of the Mac, who are not aware of the existence of the development environment and cannot make changes in it.

You update the JDK by downloading a full version from the Oracle web site. Mind you, every new JDK is installed *in addition* to the old JDK, but is set as the new default. If you want to remove the old JDK, you must do so manually, following the [instructions on the Oracle site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html#A1096903)

Comment: So what you're saying is that the Control Panel is showing the JRE version, right? Why doesn't Control Panel use the JRE version that comes with JDK (installed almost as soon as I bought my MBP 3 yrs ago)? Thanks.

Comment: How best to update my JDK version? Download the full install package from Oracle and just go through the default install instructions?

Comment: Thanks for all the info!

Answer (score 6):

If you use `jdk-7uNN-macosx-x64.dmg` via [Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html), it will install `jdk` in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` and `jre` in `/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/`.

At the command line, running `java` points to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_NN.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java`. On the other hand, Java Control Panel points to `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java`, which will automatically update.

Comment: That is my current status. Now I just need to know how to fix this.

Comment: How did you fix this?

Comment: @sudharma.puranik You can download the newer [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and install it, both of which will be updated.